# Beginners problem, Do Loop, Eigenfunction iteration

Tags: differential-equations, procedural-programming

I am trying to find the first Eigenfunction of the Laplacian (in 1D), i.e. a solution of 
$$
u''(x)=k u(x)\\
u(0)=u(1)=0
$$
with minimal $k>0$ (in this trivial example, I actually know the analytic solution but this is not the point; neither is using any built-in Eigensolver. I simply want to get acquainted with Mathematica).

To do so, I want to use the Power iteration method:

> Repeatedly applying the inverse Laplacian to an arbitrary initial
>   function will produce a sequence converging to the solution.

What I currently have is

```
ClearAll[h];
ClearAll[f];
f[x_] = 0.5 - Abs[x - 0.5];
steps = 1;
Do[
 s = NDSolve[{h''[x] == f[x], h[0] == 0, h[1] == 0}, h, {x, 0, 1}];
 f[x_] = h[x]/h[0.5] /. s;
 , steps]
```

However, when I take steps=2 or more, I get

```
   Dot::rect: Nonrectangular tensor encountered.
```

Note that this is my very first use of Mathematica, and you might have to explain obvious things to me.

**Side question:** How do I properly output intermediate results in the loop?
If I use

```
f[x_] = h[x]/h[0.5] /. s; ?f
```

I do get info on `f` but if I put

```
f[x_] = h[x]/h[0.5] /. s; ?f ; ?s
```

I get

```
Information::nomatch: "No symbol matching ?s found."
```

(Adding newlines or using commas doesn't help either. For example,

```
f[x_] = h[x]/h[0.5] /. s; 
?f ,
?s ,
```

gives no output at all, whereas

```
f[x_] = h[x]/h[0.5] /. s; 
 ?f ;
  ?s ;
```

gives

```
Information::ssym: "\!\(f; Information[\"s\", LongForm -> False]\) is not a symbol or a valid string pattern"
```

)

Comment: So at each step the definition of `f` and `s` will be interpolating functions.  What information do you want to have about them?  How do you want to display it?

Answer (score 1):

To solve the first issue, write

```
 s = NDSolve[{h''[x] == f[x], h[0] == 0, h[1] == 0}, h, {x, 0, 1}][[1]];
```

instead (notice the final brackets).

Comment: …or, use `First[]`.

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to visualize the (small) changes to the function over the course of the iterations,

```
ClearAll[h];
ClearAll[f];
f[x_] = 0.5 - Abs[x - 0.5];
steps = 4;
list = Join[
   {{#, f[#]} & /@ Subdivide[1, 100]},
   Table[
    s = NDSolveValue[{h''[x] == f[x], h[0] == 0, h[1] == 0}, 
      h, {x, 0, 1}];
    f[x_] = s[x]/s[0.5];
    {#, f[#]} & /@ Subdivide[1, 100]
    , steps]];
ListLinePlot[list, PlotLegends -> Range[0, 4]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I've also used `NDSolveValue` to get around your first problem.