# Should I implement an iteration with a While-loop?

Tags: recursion, code-generation

I have written a code that uses a guessed eigenvector (avecs) to construct a Hamiltonian (my hamiltonian depends on its own eigenvectors, so I can not solve it directly and I need to use iteration (self consistent field method)). then, utilizing the Eigensystem command, I can find the new values for energy and new eigenvectors.

Now I need to apply a Do loop or While loop, so that I can continue my calculations (replacing the new eigenvectors with the guessed(previous) eigenvector and constructing the new hamiltonian to find the new energies), until the difference between `Abs(Etotal[i] - Etotal[i - 1]) > 0.001`.

Here is a simplified part of my code, could any one help me to apply a Do/while loop?

```
NOS = 8;
NOE = 3;
avecs = Table[If[n == j, 1, 0], {j, 1, NOE}, {n, 1, NOS}]

interaction[n_, m_, j_, n1_, n2_] := 
  If[ n1 == n2, 
    If[n == m, 
      1/24 (1 - 3/(n^2 π^2) - 3/(n1^2 π^2))
        Subscript[a, j, n1] Subscript[a, j, n2], 
      ((1 + (-1)^(m + n)) m n)/((m - n)^2 (m + n)^2 π^2) 
        Subscript[a, j, n1] Subscript[a, j, n2]], 
     If[n == m, 
       ((1 + (-1)^(n1 + n2)) n1 n2)/((n1^2 - n2^2)^2 π^2)
         Subscript[a, j, n1] Subscript[a, j, n2] , 
       -((8 (-1 + (-1)^(m + n)) (-1 + (-1)^(n1 + n2)) m n n1 n2)/
           ((m - n)^2 (m + n)^2 (n1 - n2)^2 (n1 + n2)^2 π^4)) 
         Subscript[a,j, n1] Subscript[a, j, n2] ]] 
  /. 
    {Subscript[a, j, n1] -> avecs[[j, n1]], Subscript[a, j, n2] -> avecs[[j, n2]]}

interact = 
  Table[
    N[Sum[
       interaction[n, m, j, n1, n2], {n1, 1, NOS}, {n2, 1, NOS}, {j, 1, NOE}]], 
    {n, NOS}, {m, NOS}]   

eigensys = Eigensystem[interact] 
avecnew = Take[eigensys[[2]], -NOE]
energy = Take[eigensys[[1]], -NOE]
Etotal = Total[energy]
```

Comment: Do[ [whatever],{i,[startCounter],[endCounter]}], sure there is an answer out there. Look at the documentation.

Comment: It is difficult to provide advice with so little information provided.  Maybe, `FixedPoint` would work.  Also, please include in your question the code you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Beginners problem, Do Loop, Eigenfunction iteration](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114841/beginners-problem-do-loop-eigenfunction-iteration)

Comment: my advice for a starter, compose a fixed count `Do` loop first.  After you validate its working and tending to converge, convert to `While`. ( `While` will run indefinitely if you make some mistake. `Do` and `While` are so similar its simple to switch ). After getting comfortable with all that look at `Nest` and `FixedPoint`

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `Abs[Etotal[i]-Etotal[i-1]] > 0.001`?

Comment: @m_goldberg yeah, I need to consider the absolute value, Thank you so much

Comment: @bbgodfrey Thank you for your time, I added my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest implementing the iteration as follows:

```
NOS = 8;
NOE = 3;
avecs = IdentityMatrix[NOS][[;; NOE]];

interaction[n_, m_, j_, n1_, n2_, a_] :=
  If[n1 == n2,
    If[n == m,
      1/24 (1 - 3/(n^2 π^2) - 3/(n1^2 π^2)) a[[j, n1]] a[[j, n2]], 
      ((1 + (-1)^(m + n)) m n)/((m - n)^2 (m + n)^2 π^2) a[[j, n1]] a[[j, n2]]], 
    If[n == m,
      ((1 + (-1)^(n1 + n2)) n1 n2)/((n1^2 - n2^2)^2 π^2) a[[j, n1]] a[[j, n2]],
      -((8 (-1 + (-1)^(m + n))(-1 + (-1)^(n1 + n2)) m n n1 n2)/
           ((m - n)^2 (m + n)^2 (n1 - n2)^2 (n1 + n2)^2 π^4))
        a[[j, n1]] a[[j, n2]]]]

interact[avecs_] := 
  Table[
    Sum[
      N @ interaction[n, m, j, n1, n2, avecs], 
      {n1, 1, NOS}, {n2, 1, NOS}, {j, 1, NOE}], 
    {n, NOS}, {m, NOS}]

eigensys[avecs_] := Eigensystem[interact[avecs]] // Chop

next[{prev_, avecs_}] :=
  Module[{sys},
    sys = eigensys[avecs];
    {Total[Take[First @ sys, -NOE]], Take[Last @ sys, -NOE]}]

iterResults =
  NestWhileList[next, {0, avecs}, Abs[#1[[1]] - #2[[1]]] > .001 &, 2];
eTotals = iterResults[[All, 1]]
```

> `{0, 0.168095, 0.0646216, 0.0646216}`

```
eTotal = Last[eTotals]
```

> `0.0646216`

Notes

- I get rid of `Subscript`. It is really more a nuisance than a help in computation, and it is not needed for formatting output, which is its real purpose.
- I define functions for doing the computations to take the `avecs` matrix as a parameter. Parameratizing with `avecs` makes it easier to use Mathematica's functional iterators.
- I use `NestWhileList` to get the iteration history. Should you only want the final result, use `NestWhile`.

Comment: Thank you, I learned a lot from this

Comment: m_goldberg I don't know why it gives me this error:                                          
Tag List in {{0.036032,-7.18815*10^-17,0.0284966,-5.75052*10^-18,0.00527714,-1.58433*10^-18,0.001847,-6.51987*10^-19},<<6>>,{-6.51987*10^-19,<<6>>,<<20>>}}<<1>><<6>>] is Protected. >>  and also it Failed

Comment: @DelaramNematollahi. I can't tell you what is going wrong without more info. I suspect you had multiple conflicting definitions of `interaction` and/or `interact` in the notebook you where you tried to evaluate my code. I suggest trying my code in a separate notebook that you open in a fresh Mathematica session. (I just now copied the code from my answer into a new notebook in a new session and it evaluated correctly)

Comment: True, sorry, I am a  new user. It works fine in a fresh notebook. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to iterate the function in the question to convergence.  For instance, repeat the computation within a `Do`-loop until convergence is achieved, then terminate the loop with `Throw`.

```
NOS = 8; NOE = 3; ehist = {};
avecs = Table[If[n == j, 1, 0], {j, 1, NOE}, {n, 1, NOS}];

Catch[Do[
    interaction[n_, m_, j_, n1_, n2_] := If[ n1 == n2, 
        If[n == m, 1/24 (1 - 3/(n^2 π^2) - 3/(n1^2 π^2)) Subscript[a, j, n1]
        Subscript[a, j, n2], ((1 + (-1)^(m + n)) m n)/((m - n)^2 (m + n)^2 π^2)
        Subscript[a, j, n1] Subscript[a, j, n2]], If[n == m, ((1 + (-1)^(n1 + n2))
        n1 n2)/((n1^2 - n2^2)^2 π^2) Subscript[a, j, n1] Subscript[a, j, n2] ,
        -((8 (-1 + (-1)^(m + n)) (-1 + (-1)^(n1 + n2)) m n n1 n2)/((m - n)^2 (m + n)^2 
        (n1 - n2)^2 (n1 + n2)^2 π^4)) Subscript[a, j, n1] Subscript[a, j, n2] ]] /. 
        {Subscript[a, j, n1] -> avecs[[j, n1]], Subscript[a, j, n2] -> avecs[[j, n2]]};
    interact = Table[N[Sum[interaction[n, m, j, n1, n2], {n1, 1, NOS}, {n2, 1, NOS}, 
        {j, 1, NOE}]], {n, NOS}, {m, NOS}];
    eigensys = Eigensystem[interact] ;
    avecs = Take[eigensys[[2]], -NOE];
    energy = Take[eigensys[[1]], -NOE];
    Etotal = Total[energy];
    AppendTo[ehist, Etotal];
    If[j > 1 && Abs[ehist[[j]]/ehist[[j - 1]] - 1] < 10^-3, Throw[Etotal]], {j, 10}]]
(* 0.0646216 *)
```

The convergence history, if desired, is contained in `ehist`.

```
ehist
(* {0.168095, 0.0646216, 0.0646216} *)
```

Comment: @m_goldberg Thank you so much